# Onchange People Picker

Tags: 2013, javascript, jquery, people-picker

I have a problem changing a people picker in a custom form.

Need when writing or changing the value in the people picker I know, I'm using javascript using jquery.

Already tried using this code:

```
$('#[id people picker]').on('change', function(){
   alert('hi');
}
```

or

```
$('#[id people picker]').change(function(){
   alert('hi');
}
```

But there was no answer. Does anyone have another solution. Please help me because I need it soon.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you look at the HTML SP renders for a peoplepicker you will see why your code is not working.

But here's how you can attach an event to the `onchange`:

```
$(".ms-usereditor div").bind('input propertychange', function() { 
     alert("Onchange event" ); 
});
```

---

### Update

Here's a way which allows easy **access/modification for all clientside peoplepicker information**.

```
function attachPeoplePickerChange(container) {
    //container needs to be an dom element containing the peoplepicker 
    var pickerId = container.querySelector('div[spclientpeoplepicker="true"][id$="_TopSpan"]').getAttribute('id');
    //helper function to ensure all elements are already created
    var addOnChanged = function (ctx) {
        //is everything ready we need?
        if (SPClientPeoplePicker && SPClientPeoplePicker.SPClientPeoplePickerDict && SPClientPeoplePicker.SPClientPeoplePickerDict[pickerId]) {
            //get picker instance (which has a lot of useful properties btw)
            var picker = SPClientPeoplePicker.SPClientPeoplePickerDict[pickerId];
            //save old event (needs to stay in its context due to internal calls
            picker.oldChanged = picker.OnControlResolvedUserChanged;
            picker.OnControlResolvedUserChanged = function () {
                //do your code here
                console.log('OnControlResolvedUserChanged');
                //get current selected users
                console.log(picker.GetAllUserInfo());
                //let old event do its magic
                picker.oldChanged();
            };
        } else {
            //not everything was ready - wait a 10th of a sec
            setTimeout(function () { addOnChanged(ctx); }, 100);
        }
    };
    addOnChanged();
}
```

An example output (the first user was already selected when opening the page and the second was just picked): 
[image: An example output (the first user was already selected when opening the page and the second was just picked)]

Comment: Where can I call this function from my JSLink file?  Do I call it on $( document ).ready()???

I have three people pickers on my Edit and New forms, two of which I am targeting to extract people from and using that to populate the third.  How can I target just the two people picker containers I need?